# How to set width of div#a equals to div#b

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let I've two divs on my page which I want to set the same width. Consider the following markup:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <!-- content -->
        <div id="a">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="b">
</div>
```

How can I set the width of `div#b` equal to the computed width of `div#a`

Comment: `b.style.width = a.offsetWidth + "px"` where a and b variables formed by `document.getElementById('idName');`.

Comment: Did you tried it first? If yes, than please share your relevant code...

Comment: Did you mean b.style.width=a.offsetWidth+"px"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var width_a = document.getElementById("a").offsetWidth; //get the width of div#a;
document.getElementById("b").style.width = width_a + 'px' ; //set the width of div#b to width ofdiv#a
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Simply do this

```
document.getElementById("a").offsetWidth=document.getElementById("b").offsetWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
$('#b').width($('#a').width());
```

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery you can set as below:

```
$('div#b').width($('div#a').width())
```

Working Example: [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5heZu/)

Answer (score -1):

Using Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('b').style.width = document.getElementById('a').offsetWidth + 'px';
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('div#b').css({
    width: $('div#a').width()
});
```

Comment: I think people don't read comments before voting answers... Also, this user doesn't explain what does the code do...

Comment: To do it with jQuery: `$('div#b').width($('div#a').width())`

Comment: edited your post.. you mentioned `javascript` as `without jquery` that hurt my feelings.. I hope you don't mind my edit. :)